# ionic header bar scroll

Tags: ionic-framework, header

i did show hide of subheader. but when i scroll header is going upwards.

```
   <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable no-tap-scroll">
     <ion-nav-back-button>
     </ion-nav-back-button>
   </ion-nav-bar>
   <ion-nav-bar class="has-header">
   <div class="bar-stable bar-subheader no-tap-scroll" id="divslide" ng-show="quickViewDisplay"></div>
    </ion-nav-bar>

  /*-----------------------Quick View---------------------------------------*/

  #divslide {
   transition: all linear 0.1s;
   background-color: lightsalmon;
   height: 100px;
   }

 .ng-hide {
   height: 0;
   }

 #dotsDrawer {
   font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  <ion-view view-title="Dashboard">
    <ion-content overflow-scroll="false">
    <div id="dotsDrawer" class="ion-android-more-horizontal" on-drag-        up="slideUp()" on-drag-down="slideDown()"></div>
   <h1>Hide the DIV: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="quickViewDisplay"></h1>
   {{quickViewDisplay}}
   </ion-content>
  </ion-view>
```

[showing sub header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvpih.jpg)
[scroll problem header bar goes upwords](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFsMy.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Just add css to content 
ex:

```
.content{
top:88
}
```

this css shifts the content 44px below.